# Manually compile and add module r8169 (and others)

Tags: linux, compiling, kernel-modules

When typing lspci i get:

```
...
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor CO., LTD RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5413 802.11abg NIC (rev 01)
```

When navigating into the directory containing my linux kernel source and typing "make modules" i get the output

```
CHK include/config/kernel.release
CHK include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
CHK include/generated/utsrelease.h
CALL scripts/checksyscalls.sh
Builing modules stage 2
MODPOST 16 modules
```

However, this does not install two modules that i need to use the network card, namely r8169 and ath5k. They are not visible when i type modprobe -l

First of all, how does the system "know" which modules to compile and load? How do i manually tell it to compile these two modules?

If that is impossible how do i manually compile these modules so that i get a r8169.ko and a ath5k.ko file, that i can put in libs/modules/(kernel version)/kernel/drivers/net and then run insmod./r8169.ko to load into the kernel?

Please note that the source for both modules already are in the kernel tree

Comment: This process is very distribution specific.  Not the building part, but getting the OS you use to use the new kernel.  As such, can you provide your OS details

Comment: Yes im using Debian 6.0

Comment: Before I start this, you realize 6 - Squeeze is nearing EOL, and that if you upgrade to 7 - Wheezy, the driver I'm about to add to your kernel will already be included.  I'm doing research in order to write an answer.

Comment: Is upgrading possible??